# Conditional change to data frame column(s) based on values in other columns

Tags: r, dataframe

Within the simulated data set

```
n =  50
set.seed(378)
df <- data.frame(
  age = sample(c(20:90), n, rep = T), 
  sex = sample(c("m", "f"), n, rep = T, prob = c(0.55, 0.45)),
  smoker = sample(c("never", "former", "active"), n, rep = T, prob = c(0.4, 0.45, 0.15)), 
  py = abs(rnorm(n, 25, 10)),
  yrsquit = abs (rnorm (n, 10,2)),
  outcome = as.factor(sample(c(0, 1), n, rep = T, prob = c(0.8, 0.2)))
  )
```

I need to introduce some imbalance between the outcome groups (1=disease, 0=no disease). For example, subjects with the disease are older and more likely to be male. I tried

```
df1 <- within(df, sapply(length(outcome), function(x) {
if (outcome[x] == 1)  {
  age[x] <- age[x] + 15
  sex[x] <- sample(c("m","f"), prob=c(0.8,0.2))
}
}))
```

but there is no difference as shown by

```
tapply(df$sex, df$outcome, length)
tapply(df1$sex, df$outcome, length)
tapply(df$age, df$outcome, mean)
tapply(df1$age, df$outcome, mean)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of `sapply` inside `within` does not work as you expect. The function `within` does only use the returned value of `sapply`. But in your code, `sapply` returns `NULL`. Hence, `within` does not modify the data frame.

Here is an easier way to modify the data frame without a loop or `sapply`:

```
idx <- df$outcome == "1"
df1 <- within(df, {age[idx] <- age[idx] + 15; 
                   sex[idx] <- sample(c("m", "f"), sum(idx), 
                                      replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.8, 0.2))})
```

Now, the data frames are different:

```
> tapply(df$age, df$outcome, mean)
       0        1 
60.46341 57.55556 
> tapply(df1$age, df$outcome, mean)
       0        1 
60.46341 72.55556 

> tapply(df$sex, df$outcome, summary)
$`0`
 f  m 
24 17 

$`1`
f m 
2 7 

> tapply(df1$sex, df$outcome, summary)
$`0`
 f  m 
24 17 

$`1`
f m 
1 8
```